# Page not found error for an image in the dev days blog page

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, 404-not-found

There is a "Page not found" error on the [Dev Days blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/06/24/devdays/). When clicking on the image in the page, it navigate to the "Page not found" page.

> [image: Dev Days]

When inspecting the element of the image, the href is pointing to `/images/wordpress/`. That path does not exist

```
<p>
    <a href="/images/wordpress/devdays-v21.png">
        <img src="https://zgab33vy595fw5zq-zippykid.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/devdays-v21.png" alt="DevDays Countdown Screen">
    </a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link has been updated to the correct URL.  Thanks for reporting this!